# How to layer animation behind another animation in CSS and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I am struggling with figuring out how to layer 2 different animations. I would like to make the twinkling stars animation behind the moving moon animation and website tile (so that the background is essentially twinkling stars with a moving moon). Right now, it just layers on top of the moon animation and title, completely covering them, and the position is off. I am relatively new to HTML so please excuse me if my question is obvious. TIA

```css
@keyframes moon {
  0% {
    box-shadow: -150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px white;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

.stars,
.twinkling {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: #000 url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.twinkling {
  background: transparent url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 0;
  -moz-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
}

html {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black 80%, #041931, #fff);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 45%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  background: none;
}

div {
  background: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.moon {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  animation: moon 20s linear infinite alternate;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -10rem 0 whitesmoke;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
<style>
  div {
    margin: 10%;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <h1 id="text">
    <center> Welcome to my Site! </center>
  </h1>
  <div class="moon"></div>
  <div class="stars"></div>
  <div class="twinkling"></div>
  <div class="maintext">
    <h2>This is text below the animations</h2>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.moon').css("animation-play-state", "paused");
    }, 20000)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not add `z-index` to all the elements as the positioning looked irregular. I just removed the z-index on other parts and included them in the relevant parts i.e. `moon`, `stars` and `twinkling`.

I also had to remove the margin set on div elements. View the demo in full-screen mode.

```css
@keyframes moon {
  0% {
    box-shadow: -150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px white;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

.stars,
.twinkling {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: #000 url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: -3;
}

.twinkling {
  background: transparent url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  -moz-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  z-index: -2;
}

html, body {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

.moon {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  animation: moon 20s linear infinite alternate;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -10rem 0 whitesmoke;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

#text, .maintext { color: white; text-align: center; margin-top: 25px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<style>

</style>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1 id="text">
      <center> Welcome to my Site! </center>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="animation-part">
    <div class="twinkling"></div>
    <div class="moon"></div>
    <div class="stars"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="maintext">
    <h2>This is text below the animations</h2>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.moon').css("animation-play-state", "paused");
    }, 20000)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is awesome! Is there a reason why "Welcome to my Site!" is no longer visible?

Comment: It was because the styling was not perfect. I had to remove the height of 45%. Add color to text.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it would be possible to keep the fade at the bottom with the twinkling stars? It disappears when we place it behind the moon

Comment: Check the other answer. It would be helpful. I thought you wanted a full-screen body background. But I would suggest you use a responsive framework https://semantic-ui.com/ to develop your web page.  Writing code for each and every section is time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

**This z-index and css tweaking will solve your problem.**

```css
@keyframes moon {
  0% {
    box-shadow: -150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px white;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 150px 0px 0px 0px white;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

html {
  background-image: linear-gradient(black 80%, #041931, #fff);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 45%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.stars,
.twinkling {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: #000 url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) top center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
}

.twinkling {
  background: transparent url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: -1;
  -moz-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
  animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
}

.moon {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  animation: moon 20s linear infinite alternate;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -10rem 0 whitesmoke;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="text">
    <center> Welcome to my Site! </center>
  </h1>
  <div class="moon"></div>
  <div class="stars"></div>
  <div class="twinkling"></div>
  <div class="maintext">
    <h2>This is text below the animations</h2>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.moon').css("animation-play-state", "paused");
    }, 20000)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```